# Partition a range to n parts such that all the number in the range appear in subsets

Tags: algorithm

I need to generate some random data of N subscribers for M hours

Let's say subscriber id range = 1-20

Number of hours = 20

For each hour number of subscriber used for data generation : 4-6

How to randomly pick subscriber ids such that all the subscribers are picked from the range over 20 hours and can also repeat in multiple hours data.

e.g for hour 1 , subscriber id : 1-5

for hour 2 , subscriber id : 4-7 (4 and 5 repeat from previous hour)

for hour 3 , subscriber id : 6-10(6 and 7 repeat from previous hour)

In above data subscriber range is moved sequentially to ensure data for all subscribers get generated but I want to make it random while ensuring conditions:

- Each subscriber (1-20) appears at least once in 20 hours data.
- Subscribers can appear multiple times in multiple hour data.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is it always a range, or could be hour2: 1,5,9 - for example? If it can, just put all subscribers first randomly, and then fill the remaining slots, also randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting the first range randomly. This will give you a range of `[x,y]`.
In the next hour, add to `x` a number that is randomly chosen in the range of `[0, y-x]` and the end of the new range is the beginning of it plus a random number between 4 and 6. All of this is of course `mod 20` (or whatever your subscriber id range max is).

In order to ensure you get to all clients, set the ranges to a minimum so that you progress through the subscriber list fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Start with creating a random permutation of the numbers in the range of 1..N. Then assign the subscriber referenced by the i-th item in the permutation to the (i % M) hour. This will satisfy your first requirement (every subscriber should participate in at least 1 hour).

Now the second stage should be iterating through the hours and while there are available slots left (from the 4-6 slots you have for each hour) randomize a number in the range of 1..N and assign the corresponding subscriber to that slot.